# Get service name on some old Linux OS

Tags: command, services

```
# cat /etc/system-release
CloudLinux Server release 6.<...>

# systemctl
-bash: systemctl: command not found

# service --status-all
<service description> is running
<some service description> is running
...
Table: filter
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination

Usage: ipaliases {start|stop|restart|reload}
Table: filter
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    cP-Firewall-1-INPUT  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    cP-Firewall-1-INPUT  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
...
```

Nothing like some "normal" results like [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/407075/how-to-read-service-status-all-results), just look at iptables fragment!
How can I find the real name of the service and not its fancy description ?

Comment: what does `ls /etc/init.d/*` give you?

Comment: Oh wow, `ipchains`: you're predating `iptables`. And just how old is this system!?

Comment: `ls /etc/init.d/*` is the correct answer, thank you (a link to `/etc/rc.d/init.d` containing all the service scripts, AFAIU). I will accept your answer if you want, @justsomeguy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you could try to list out the services on an older system is:

```
ls /etc/init.d/*
```